# How to simulate middle mouse click in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, mouse

The middle click button of the mouse I use is broken, so I'd like to simulate it by pressing left and right mouse buttons at the same time.

In Freya, I could do:

```
xinput set-prop "Wireless Optical Mouse" "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 1
```

But in Loki, I get this message:

```
property 'Evdev Middle Button Emulation' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

I'd like the simulation to persist across reboots and suspends.

Comment: Another question would be:  How to simulate middle click on a notebook touchpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working. Firstly I needed to change the property name. Then I could use that with the xinput command inside ~/.profile. Thanks to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211863/206357) Unix Stackexchange answer, I am able to execute the xinput command after each unlock.

Here's what I added to my ~/.profile:

```
simulate_mouse_middle() {
    xinput set-prop "Wireless Optical Mouse" "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
}

simulate_mouse_middle

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'" | \
(
    while true; do
        read X
        if echo $X | grep "desktop-unlock" &> /dev/null; then
            simulate_mouse_middle
        fi
     done
) &
```